# newwrite and read in with umlauts

Tags: write

I write the file `out.csv`, which contains umlauts and tried to read it in.
How can I make this work?

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\out
\immediate\openout\out=out.csv
\foreach[count=\n from 0] \word in {ä, ö, ü, ß, x, y}{
\immediate\write\out{\n; \word }% works not
%\immediate\write\out{\n; \detokenize{\word} }% works not too
}
\immediate\closeout\out
\input{out.csv}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=false]{out.csv}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Ulrike Fischer in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58155687#58155687), another possibility is to use [@egreg `\protected@iwrite`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542425/38080):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\makeatletter
\long\def\protected@iwrite#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  #2%
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
\newcommand{\mywrite}[2]{\protected@iwrite#1{}{#2}}%

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newwrite\out
\immediate\openout\out=out.csv
\foreach[count=\n from 0] \word in {ä, ö, ü, ß, x, y}{
    \mywrite\out{\n; \word ; \word}% now it works
}
\immediate\closeout\out
\input{out.csv}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header=false]{out.csv}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, looking good; should work with that. My original code does not work further with that (same error). Maybe my fault, I have to look.

Comment: Can I ask you again here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/599036/46023

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand `\word` before applying `\detokenize`

```
\immediate\write\out{\n: \detokenize\expandafter{\word}}
```

[image]

There's no need to do `\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\word}`, because `\detokenize` expands tokens while looking for `{`.

For more complex applications, you might try `\protected@iwrite`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596328/4427

Comment: What about using your `\protected@iwrite` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542425/38080? Maybe it's more general...

Comment: @Rmano That's indeed another good idea.

Comment: it really is a Ulrike's idea https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58155687#58155687, I just went over to learn ;-)